# Use an AngularJS filter in Array.prototype.sort does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I'm trying to sort an array, using the values returned by filters. When debugging, I see that the filters does not return strings but `TrustedValueHolderType`... and so the sort does not work.

I get the same behaviour if I use the native `orderByFilter` instead of `Array.prototype.sort`.

```
function orderFamilies(families) {
            var ordered = families.sort(function(f1, f2) {
                // f1, f2 are strings
                // translateFamilyFilter is stateless
                var f1Translated = translateFamilyFilter(f1);
                // var f1Translated = translateFamilyFilter(f1).toString() works but I'm not sure if it's viable
                var f2Translated = translateFamilyFilter(f2);
                return f1Translated - f2Translated;
            });
            return ordered;
}

families = [ 'Security', 'Environment', 'Professional'];
```

`translateFamily` is a custom filter which converts the family name in its translation key then uses `$translate.instant` (so no async operation here).

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: post the `families` values

Comment: what filter? `$translate`? how are you using it?

Comment: Edit with content of `families` and my custom filter